# Deleting a dynamic array from another function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, dynamic, delete-operator

Exactly as it says. I create a dynamic array in one function, then give the pointer to another one for adding a new element to the end and try to delete[] it. First it gave me a wntdll.pdb not loaded, which I quickly downloaded. Then, it just causes an exception upon deletion. I think it's something to do with protection but I have no idea on how to circumvent it.

Any ideas?

By the way, it loads a "delete_scalar.cpp" file on line 32

```
_free_dbg(block, _UNKNOWN_BLOCK);
```

My code (short version):

```
int addNode(long *oldArray, int size) {
    long *newArray = new long[size + 1];
    long *bufArray = oldArray;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        newArray[i] = oldArray[i];
    }
    oldArray = newArray;
    delete[] bufArray;  //the problem line
    size++;
    return size;
}
```

My code (long version, and yes, all the outdated solutions are a part of the curriculum, and are mandatory):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void convertToBin(string const nameIn, string const nameOut);
void readFile(string const fileName);
long *getNewArr(long **arrMatrix, int *arrSizes, int arrNum);
int addNode(long *oldArray, int size);
void outputArr(long *resArr);

void main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    string preinput = "input.txt", input = "input.bin", output = "output.txt";
    convertToBin(preinput, input);
    readFile(input);
    cout << "Готово!\n";       //Done!
}
                  //this is where the array is created
void readFile(string fileName) {            
    cout << "Чтение файла\n";  //reading the file
    ifstream streamIn;
    streamIn.open(fileName, ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (!streamIn.is_open()) {
        cout << "Ошибка чтения файла\n";  //file reading error
        return;
    }
    cout << "Получение размеров массивов\n";  //get array sizes
    int arrNum;
    streamIn.read((char*)&arrNum, sizeof(int));
    int *arrSize = new int[arrNum];
    for (int i = 0; i < arrNum; i++)
    {
        streamIn.read((char*)&arrSize[i], sizeof(int));
    }
    cout << "Создание первоначальных массивов\n";   //setup initial arrays
    long **arrMatrix = new long *[arrNum];
    for (int i = 0; i < arrNum; i++)
    {
        arrMatrix[i] = new long[arrSize[i]];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arrNum; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < arrSize[i]; j++) {
            streamIn.read((char*)&arrMatrix[i][j], sizeof(long));
        }
    streamIn.close();
    outputArr(getNewArr(arrMatrix, arrSize, arrNum));
    cout << "Очистка памяти\n";              //memory cleanup
    for (int i = 0; i < arrNum; i++)
        delete[] arrMatrix[i];
    delete[] arrMatrix;
    delete[] arrSize;
}

long *getNewArr(long **arrMatrix, int *arrSizes, int arrNum) {
    cout << "Создание нового массива\n";        //creating new array
    long *newArr = new long [0];
    int newArrSize = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrSizes[0]; i++) {     //the heart of the
        long x = arrMatrix[0][i];               //program. multiplies
        bool isCommon = 1;                      //x sets, outputs the
        for (int j = 1; j < arrNum; j++) {      //result preceeded by
            isCommon = 0;                       //size.
            for (int k = 0; k < arrSizes[j]; k++)
                if (x == arrMatrix[j][k]) { isCommon = 1; break; }
        }
        if (isCommon) {
            newArrSize = addNode(newArr, newArrSize);
            newArr[newArrSize - 1] = x;
        }
    }
    addNode(newArr, newArrSize);                  
    for (int i = 0; i < newArrSize; i++)
        newArr[i + 1] = newArr[i];
    newArr[0] = newArrSize;
    return newArr;
}

int addNode(long *oldArray, int size) {           //the problem function
    long *newArray = new long[size + 1];
    long *bufArray = oldArray;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        newArray[i] = oldArray[i];
    }
    oldArray = newArray;
    delete[] bufArray;                              //the problem line
    size++;
    return size;
}

void outputArr(long *resArr) {
    cout << "Сохранение нового массива\n";          //saving new array
    ofstream streamOut;
    streamOut.open("output.txt");
    if (!streamOut.is_open()) {
        cout << "Ошибка чтения файла\n";            //file read error
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= resArr[0]; i++) {
        streamOut << resArr[i] << " ";
    }
    streamOut.close();
    delete[] resArr;
}

void convertToBin(string const nameIn, string const nameOut)   
{                                                 //he has us bloody convert
    ifstream streamIn;                            //to binary before doing
    streamIn.open(nameIn, ios_base::in);          //anything.

    ofstream streamOut;
    streamOut.open(nameOut, ios_base::out | ios_base::binary);

    if (!(streamIn.is_open() && streamOut.is_open()))
    {
        cout << "Ошибка чтения файлов!\n";
        return;
    }
    int x;
    while (!streamIn.eof()) {
        streamIn >> x;
        streamOut.write((char*)&x, sizeof(int));
    }
    streamIn.close();   streamOut.close();
}
```

Comment: `oldArray = newArray` - in `addNode` means *nothing* to the caller of this function. Their argument passed as `oldArray` remains unchanged, and is now a dangling pointer, and you've leaked memory (the new allocation), upon function return). Worse, future calls now feed a dangling, already-deleted pointer back to `addNode`, which will *likely* puke all over your terminal. Change `long *oldArray` in the argument list to `long *& oldArray`

Comment: That was... quicker than I thought. And absolutely the problem.
Welp, back to learning pointers. Thanks.
Do you wanna actually answer this one or do I just copy this?

Comment: That isn't a pointer problem; its a lack of lvalue reference to a pointer problem. The pointer was fine; it was just being passed by value. As C++, changing to pass the pointer by reference is an easy fix.

Comment: @JohnnyCache You could avoid all of these issues if you used `std::vector` instead of raw memory and pointers.

Comment: All the outdated solutions are a part of the curriculum, and are mandatory. Literally written up there. Trust me, if I could use std::vector, I'd be using C#.

Comment: *I'd be using C#* BLASPHEMY! Where's my stake and kindling?